# find the id by class, and filter result by another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get first `<li>` `id` where class name `my_class` exists and if `<span>` class `Time` contains "`:`" using jquery.

Here is my HTML :

```
<ul class="list">
   <li id="myID-1" class=""> 
        <span class="Time">00h : 10m</span>
   </li>
   <li id="myID-2" class="my_class">
        <span class="Time">01h : 08m</span>
   </li>
   <li id="myID-3" class="my_class"> 
        <span class="Time">waiting</span>                                       
   </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var ID = $(".my_class").attr("id");
```

But how to filter results by class `Time`?

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".my_class:has(.Time:contains(:))").attr("id");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bnp2n0t0/

Comment: Missing `.Time:contains(:)` : *" if span class 'Time' contains(:) "*.

Comment: Give me a second... finishing the JSFiddle with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".my_class").find("span.Time:contains(':')").parent().attr("id");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bnp2n0t0/1/)

Comment: @Brijesh Bhatt: `attr` always returns the result from the first match, so `:first` is not needed

Comment: @Brijesh Bhatt: That's not to say bouncing up and down the DOM like this is optimal by any means (makes me dizzy just reading it) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
$(".my_class").each(function(){
if($(this).child().hasClass("Time").text().indexOf(':') > -1)
{
     var Id = $(this).attr("id");
}
});
```

Thanks, Hayat S.

Comment: jQuery generally does not require an `each` (which should be avoided in most cases as it is less efficient). Also your example will match all divs with `.Time` instead of just the first.